# when overflow: auto, padding-bottom is not seen

Tags: css, overflow

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur amet, vitae fuga provident et quae aut minus voluptate quidem maiores at recusandae sit deleniti quia dolore, illum reiciendis! Hic, optio Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit accusantium, obcaecati dicta unde repellat illo maxime! Magni officiis, culpa nihil, sequi aliquid vel voluptas quidem laboriosam, omnis nam fuga veniam.</div>
</div>
```

```
.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v6yjLdnp/

Why doesn't the `padding-bottom` work in this case when scrolling? And how do I make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean the padding at the bottom of the scrolled content. This seems to be a browser issue - see the comments. But with the following code it should work properly in *all* browsers.

Transfer some of the settings to the container, then it works as desired:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur amet, vitae fuga provident et quae aut minus voluptate quidem maiores at recusandae sit deleniti quia dolore, illum reiciendis! Hic, optio Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Fugit accusantium, obcaecati dicta unde repellat illo maxime! Magni officiis, culpa nihil, sequi aliquid vel voluptas quidem laboriosam, omnis nam fuga veniam.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the end result looks exactly the same as in the JSFiddle.

Comment: @GuyIncognito No it doesn't: If you scroll down, there is a padding of 20px at the bottom (yellow background), which isn't there in the fiddle of the question.

Comment: The padding is there in the JSFiddle on my browser. I don't know if it's because of the browser (Chrome).

Comment: Hmm. On firefox there is no padding-bottom in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably be caused by the scroll bars.

This is a workaround with using pseudo elements in css, but it might solve your problem:

`.content::after { content: ''; display: block; width: 100%; height: 20px; }`

EDIT: Remove the padding bottom of the content element to make it work in all browsers:

`.content { padding-bottom: 0px; }`

Comment: It seems to be a browser issue (Crome yes, Firefox no) - see my answer. So this workaround would result in a double "padding" (40px high) on the browsers which *do*   show the padding-bottom...

Comment: So you can just get rid of it in the content element. thanks for the comment, see my edit.